# Does System.Diagnostic get its data by querying the WMI or by other means?

Tags: c#, .net, wmi

Does System.Diagnostic get its data by querying the WMI or by other means?
Is WMI querying the most basic way all these operations employ to get system information such as running processes, or are there even more direct methods?

Comment: It is very much dependent upon the data you're referring to. You'll have to be more specific than just `System.Diagnostic` in order to get useful answers. Either that or, as Adam suggested, step through the code yourself. But keep in mind that where the information is obtained is all very much abstracted away by design. You aren't supposed to know or care where the info came from. If you're trying to implement such functionality yourself, update the question to be more specific about what information you want to get at.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, it doesn't use WMI.  It uses direct native API calls via internal classes within the System.Win32 namespace in mscorlib.dll and System.dll.  Most classes like PerformanceCounter and EventLog just access the registry which uses native calls to advapi32.dll.  Other functionality like getting a process list use calls in winnt.dll or kernel32.dll depending on the version of Windows.  You can find more information about the native Win32 calls used [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724953%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) and more detailed information about performance counters [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa371643%28v=VS.85%29.aspx).

You can verify this using [dotPeek](http://www.jetbrains.com/decompiler/) or [Reflector.NET](http://www.reflector.net/) and examining System.Diagnostics in mscorlib.dll and System.dll.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to find out for yourself you can step into the .NET framework source code.

Steps here on how to do it through Visual Studio: http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/arik/archive/2010/07/12/step-into-net-framework-4-0-source-code.aspx